# PoDoFo library crash in ios 7 but working in ios 6 and earlier

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, ios7, podofo

i am using [PoDoFo library](https://github.com/xil3f/podofo_iOS_sample) for standard PDF annotation it working ios6 and earlier when i upgrade app into ios7 it display EXC_BAD_ACCESS like this

[image]

it crash in this code

```
  PdfMemDocument *doc1 = [APDFManager createPdfForFileAtPath:pdfpath_name];

+(PdfMemDocument*)createPdfForFileAtPath:(NSString*)path
{

    PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument* doc = new PoDoFo::PdfMemDocument([path UTF8String]);

    return (PdfMemDocument*)doc;
}
```

Comment: please use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643771/how-can-i-use-the-podofo-library-for-annotating-pdfs-on-ios if you still having problem you can mail to podofo

Comment: @AshutoshMishra PdfMemDocument *doc1 is release so i can't pass doc1 object

Comment: So have you found any solution?

Comment: no you have any idea for this issue ?

Comment: I have found whole document for you . If you want it you can skype me at ashumishra224

Comment: @kirtimali I know its old, were you able to fix the issue ? Can you help ?

Comment: @iphonic sorry i forgot the solution

Comment: I got it working, may be it was the same solution for you. The Main class from where the creation was getting called should be non-arc.

Answer (score 2):

I have been personally using podofo in both iOS6 and 7 but didn't find any of these issues.
Try this piece of code instead for Creating PdfMemDocument*

```
    PdfMemDocument *memDoc;
    PdfFileInputStream fileInputStream(filePath);
    char *srcBuffer = new char[fileInputStream.GetFileLength()];
    size_t srcLen = fileInputStream.GetFileLength();
    fileInputStream.Read(srcBuffer,srcLen);


    PdfOutputDevice outputDevice(filePath);

    outputDevice.Write(srcBuffer,srcLen);

    memDoc.Load(srcBuffer,srcLen);

    return memDoc;
```

Comment: Do you have sample project or, something? But the code above too crash on `memDoc.Load`

Comment: The only way you could have a better crash log is if you compile Podofo of your own rather than getting an already compiled version.I am sure something is not linking correctly with iOS 7. The simplest way to compile podofo is to create a new Xcode project and add files to it. You can use the dependencies from the project you already have. Hope this helps